# Run-time Error 3131 Syntax Error in FROM Clause - Microsoft access

Tags: ms-access

When I run this code, it is telling me the problem is coming from the line "Me.sub_dellist.Form.RecordSource = SQL"

```
Private Sub btnsearch_Click()

    Dim SQL As String
    
    SQL = "SELECT DEL.ID, DEL.Company, DEL.Address, DEL.Country, DEL.Category, DEL.Activity, DEL.[Products Involved] " _
        & "FROM DEL" _
        & "WHERE [Products Involved] LIKE '*" & Me.txtkeywords & "*" _
        & "ORDER BY DEL.Company;"

    Me.sub_dellist.Form.RecordSource = SQL
    Me.sub_dellist.Form.Requery
```

Comment: Need to add a space in front of quote mark at end of each line (except the last one). `Debug.Print SQL` and you should see the constructed SQL statement and what is wrong with it. SQL is a reserved word, better variable would be strSQL.

Comment: Also missing apostrophe after the second *.

Comment: Why set the form RecordSource? Could just apply filter criteria to form.

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Answer (score 0):

Do as *June* suggests, apply a filter:

```vb
Dim Filter As String

' To apply a filter.
Filter = "[Products Involved] LIKE '*" & Me!txtkeywords.Value & "*'"
Me.Filter = Filter
Me.FilterOn = True

' To ignore a filter (show all records).
Me.FilterOn = False
```